# MySQL: select a row if that row is equal for every user

Tags: mysql

In my database I have 5 fix users, lets say user1, ..., user5.

Furthermore I have a table

```
month(name, finished, month, year)
```

where name is VARCHAR (the name of one of the five users) and the others are INTEGER. In row `finished`, 0 means not finished and 1 means `finished` (Note that finished does not mean 'the month is over' in this context). Every user has an entry for each month.
I'm struggling to find a query which returns me the months where every user has the entry `finished = 1`.

```
SELECT month FROM month
```

obviously returns months, where other users can have finished=0

```
SELECT month FROM month WHERE finished=1
```

returns the finished months (multiple times), while other users can have `finished=0` in this same month and I would have to check in the code if there are months appearing five times (which would mean that month is finished by all users).

Now, without creating triggers or similiar constructs, is there a way to check the desired requirement directly in the SQL-query?

**Addendum**: I know that a table `monthAll(month, year, finishedAll)` would be a solution, but setting it to `finishedAll=1` if all five users have finished a certain month would equally require additional code in my JavaScript due to the fact how the whole program is constructed.

Comment: Side note: I'd suggest using different naming convention(at least for tables). I'd never figure out that `month.name` actually stores username...

Answer (score 1):

If there are 5 rows per month (1 for every user), this will do:

```
SELECT m.year, m.month 
FROM month AS m
GROUP BY m.year, m.month
HAVING SUM(finished) = 5 ;
```